# Lebesgue differentiation theorem for monotone functions via Vitali covering lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lipschitz-functions, outer-measure

I was reading [LECTURES ON LIPSCHITZ ANALYSIS](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf) by Juha Heinonen and at the Theorem 3.2 he gives a proof of Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem for monotone functions. He says that we can easily (using the Vitali covering lemma and the definitions of $D^+f(x)$ and $D^-f(x)$) check the following:

If $E_q = \{ x \in (a,b); D^+f(x) > q \}$ and $E_p = \{ x \in (a,b); D^-f(x) < p \}$ then

1. $q|E_q| \leq |f(E_q)|$,
2. $|f(E_p)| \leq p|E_p|$.

But I couldn't prove it on my own. I found the calculations [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/upper-and-lower-derivatives-of-real-valued-functions) but I was wondering if has another way more direct for check it "easily" like the book claim.

Thanks!

Notes:

1. f is a increasing functions,
2. $|\cdot|$ is the Lebesgue measure,
3. $D^+f(x) = \limsup_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$,
4. $D^-f(x) = \liminf_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Comment: Hi. Could you figure out how to check those claims? Have the same problem.

Comment: You could see the calculations in the link above or check this in the measure and Integral by Wheeden and Zygmund. I don't know how to check this easy as the notes claim.